# JQuery / Javascript - Mouse Location completely off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a 'draw' app, which allows the user to draw something by dragging their mouse over a canvas.

I want to draw a 'pixel' where the user drags their mouse, however: The location of the mouse and the location where the 'pixels' get drawn are not the same.
I've searched all over the internet but I don't know what the difference is with my version and with theirs.

Image: [image]

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Drawer</title>
    <script src="jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripting/draw.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="drawGround" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var drawSize = 3;
  var canDrawCanvas = false;
  const canvasID = "#drawGround";

  document.onmouseup = function() {
    canDrawCanvas = false;
  };

  $(canvasID).mousedown(function() {
    canDrawCanvas = true;
  });
  $(canvasID).mousemove(function(event) {
    if (canDrawCanvas) handleDrawing(event);

  });

  function handleDrawing(mouseEvent) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID.substring(1));
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillRect(mouseEvent.pageX, mouseEvent.pageY, drawSize, drawSize);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="drawGround" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: pageX and pageY give you the position of mouse pointer onto entire page, not in your canvas so try to locate/calculate what is the relative position of the pointer, not absolute.

Comment: Use `offsetX` and `offsetY` instead of `pageX` and `pageY`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of scaling the canvas object with the "style" attribute, you should use the "width" and "height"-attributes in the canvas-element.

```
<canvas id="drawGround" width="500px" height="500px" style="margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Then use the `offsetX` and `offsetY` parameters instead of `pageX` and `pageY` to get the tip position of the mouse:

```
function handleDrawing(mouseEvent) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID.substring(1));
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.fillRect(mouseEvent.offsetX, mouseEvent.offsetY, drawSize, drawSize);
}
```